# Exceptions when using NetMQ from powershell

Tags: powershell, zeromq, netmq

I'm using the NetMQ library from Powershell but keep getting the following exception.

#### Environment

```
NetMQ Version: NetMQ.4.0.0.1   
Operating System: Windows Server 2012
.NET Version:  4
```

I'm using this from PowerShell:

`$pubSocket = New-Object NetMQ.Sockets.ResponseSocket -Args ("@tcp://localhost:5556")`

However it throws the following exception:

`New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Exception of type 'NetMQ.NetMQException' was thrown."
At line:1 char:14
+ ... pubSocket = New-Object NetMQ.Sockets.ResponseSocket -Args ("@tcp://lo ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`

Answer (score 0):

Not a nice error message, eh!

Whilst I can't help directly, I can offer some advice on how to get more of the exception details:

```
try {
    ...your code here...
}
catch {
    throw $_.Exception.ToString()
}
```

Hopefully this will give more details.

You can even dig through the `Exception` object to find more detail e.g. `$_.Exception.InnerException`

To illustrate the difference:
[image: Exception details]